# Spring Data JPA to accept only the time to persist data

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to persist only the time in HH:mm:ss format and the startDay only as a day of the week like 'Monday', 'Tuesday' etc

using Java8, Spring Data JPA and MySQL

```
| startTime |startDay
  08:00:00    Monday
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What did you do? Can you show some code

Answer (score 1):

To define an Entity covering your requirements you could use java.sql.Time for the startTime which is mapped to [MySQL TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) and the java.time.DayOfWeek enumeration for startDay .

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Event {
  private java.sql.Time startTime;
  private java.time.DayOfWeek startDay;
  ...
}
```

For more details in JPA related date and time mappings have a look at http://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-jpa-date-and-time/ . For JPA enumeration mappings check https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-enum-mappings/ .

Note that in case you are using Hibernate 5 you could also use java.time.LocalTime instead of java.sql.Time for the startTime.